# Finding highest value in range key

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb defined with `RangeKey` as `time_in_millis`. Now, I want to find the **latest** value of a given object based on the **HashKey**.

I am trying this

```
MyObject key = new MyObject();
key.setHashKey("hash_key_of_object");

DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject> q = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject>().withHashKeyValues(key)
```

next, I am not sure how to specific to find the highest value in range key.

Answer (score 3):

**ScanIndexForward** can be used to sort the range key in descending order. The first item in the result set is the maximum value of the range key (sort key is otherwise called range key).

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject>().withHashKeyValues(myObject)
                .withScanIndexForward(false);

myObjectList = dynamoDBMapper.query(MyObject.class, queryExpression);
```

> If ScanIndexForward is true, DynamoDB returns the results in the order
>   in which they are stored (by sort key value). This is the default
>   behavior. If ScanIndexForward is false, DynamoDB reads the results in
>   reverse order by sort key value, and then returns the results to the
>   client.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, What if i have to find highest value of range key which is *greater* than the provided value? i.e., I want to find latest record changes as of jun 02, 2017 (time would be in miliseconds). how can i do this.